# Why am I getting a 'success' response but my form data is not being uploaded to my MySQL database using Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I am currently working on a piece of code that will pop up a modal. Once the user fill outs the modal they click submit and the data should upload to my database. Everything leading up to hitting submit works. When the user hits submit, the modal disappears and it appears to work but the data doesn't upload to my database. My code isn't throwing any errors on the page or even in my logs. The only response that I get is "success" within my response tab.

Here is my ajax for my code:

```
function createFile(){  
  //Fill In
  var sdate = $("#startDate").val();
  var edate = $("#endDate").val();
  var sdatef = new Date(sdate);
  var edatef = new Date(edate);
  var startdatetime = formatDate(sdatef);
  var enddatetime = formatDate(edatef); 
  var createdby = document.getElementById("create_createdby").value;
  var itemold = document.getElementById("create_itemold").value;
  var itemnew = document.getElementById("create_itemnew").value;
  var approver1 = document.getElementById("create_approver1").value;
  var approver2 = document.getElementById("create_approver2").value;
  var approver3 = document.getElementById("create_approver3").value;
  var approver4 = document.getElementById("create_approver4").value;
  var approver5 = document.getElementById("create_approver5").value;
  var note = document.getElementById("create_note").value;
  
  createFileAjax(createdby, itemold, itemnew, startdatetime, enddatetime, approver1, approver2, approver3, approver4, approver5, note);
}
function createFileAjax(createdby, itemold, itemnew, startdatetime, enddatetime, approver1, approver2, approver3, approver4, approver5, note){
  var errorMSG = "<span style='color:green'>Please Wait</span>";
  
  if (createdby == ""){
    document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = "Please add a name!";
    return;
  }
  
  if (itemold == ""){
    document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = "Please add the current item!";
    return;
  }
  
  if (itemnew == ""){
    document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = "Please add the new item!";
    return;
  }
  
  if (approver1 == ""){
    document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = "Please add at least 2 approvers!";
    return;
  }
  
  if (approver2 == ""){
    document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = "Please add at least 2 approvers!";
    return;
  }
  
  if (note == ""){
    document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = "Please add a message!";
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = errorMSG;
  if (errorMSG != "<span style='color:green'>Please Wait</span>"){
    return
  }
  
  $.ajax({
    url: './ajax/submitData.ajax.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      "create": 1,
      "createdby": createdby,
      "itemold": itemold,
      "itemnew": itemnew,
      "startdatetime": startdatetime,
      "enddatetime": enddatetime,
      "approver1":  approver1,
      "approver2": approver2,
      "approver3": approver3,
      "approver4": approver4,
      "approver5": approver5,
      "note": note,
    },
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response) {
     //console.log(response);
       if (response == "success"){
         closeAndClearCreateModal();
       } else {
         document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = response;
       }
     }
  });
 }
```

Now here is the modal itself:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="createModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="createModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="createModalLabel">New Deviation</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <span id="errorMSGCreate" class="errorMSG"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="create_deviation_row" class="row inputSection">
            <div class="col-4 inputRow">
              Created By:
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 inputRow">
              <input class="createInput" maxlength="49" id="create_createdby"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 inputRow">
              Old Item:
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 inputRow">
              <input class="createInput" maxlength="49" id="create_itemold"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 inputRow">
              New Item:
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 inputRow">
              <input class="createInput" maxlength="49" id="create_itemnew"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 inputRow">
              Start Date:
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 inputRow">
              <input autocomplete="off" id="startDate" width="200" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 inputRow">
              End Date:
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 inputRow">
              <input autocomplete="off" id="endDate" width="200" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 inputRow">
              Approvers: <a class="default-link" onclick="resetApprovers()">Clear</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 inputRow">
              <table class="approverTable">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1<sup>st</sup> Approver:</td>
                    <td><select id="create_approver1" onchange="getApprovers(2)">
                    <option value=""> </option>
                    <option value="Name One">Name One</option>
                    <option value="Name Two">Name Two</option>
                    <option value="Name Three">Name Three</option>
                    <option value="Name Four">Name Four</option>
                    <option value="Name Five">Name Five</option>
                    <option value="Name Six">Name Six</option>
                    </select></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="create_approver2 hide">
                    <td>2<sup>nd</sup> Approver:</td>
                    <td><select id="create_approver2" onchange="getApprovers(3)"></select></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="create_approver3 hide">
                    <td>3<sup>rd</sup> Approver:</td>
                    <td><select id="create_approver3" onchange="getApprovers(4)"></select></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="create_approver4 hide">
                    <td>4<sup>th</sup> Approver:</td>
                    <td><select id="create_approver4" onchange="getApprovers(5)"></select></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="create_approver5 hide">
                    <td>5<sup>th</sup> Approver:</td>
                    <td><select id="create_approver5"></select></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 inputRow">
              Comments:
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 inputRow">
              <textarea id="create_note"  class="textfield createInput" cols="40" rows="4" wrap="on" maxlength="490"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createFile()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally here is my code where I call to insert the data to my database:

```
$db = "APPS";

if (isset($_POST['create'])){
  if(isset($_POST['createdby']) && isset($_POST['itemold']) 
    && isset($_POST['itemnew']) && isset($_POST['startdatetime']) && isset($_POST['enddatetime']) 
    && isset($_POST['approver1']) && isset($_POST['approver2']) && isset($_POST['approver3']) 
    && isset($_POST['approver4']) && isset($_POST['approver5']) && isset($_POST['note'])){
    
    echo createFile($_POST['createdby'], $_POST['itemold'], $_POST['itemnew'], 
    $_POST['startdatetime'], $_POST['enddatetime'], $_POST['approver1'], $_POST['approver2'], 
    $_POST['approver3'], $_POST['approver4'], $_POST['approver5'], $_POST['note']);
    
  } else {
    echo "ERROR: INVALID INPUT";
  }
}

function createFile($createdby, $itemold, $itemnew, $startdatetime, $enddatetime, $approver1, $approver2, $approver3, $approver4, $approver5, $note){
  global $db, $loginname;
  
  $dbs = new DatabaseApps($db);
  $conn = $dbs->getConnection();
  
  $query = "INSERT INTO deviations (datetime, createdby, itemold, itemnew, startdatetime, enddatetime, approver1, approver2, approver3, approver4, approver5, note) VALUES (NOW(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  
  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss", $createdby, $itemold, $itemnew, $startdatetime, $enddatetime, $approver1, $approver2, $approver3, $approver4, $approver5, $note);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
  } else {
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));
  }
  
  $dbs->closeConnection();
  
  return "success";
}
```

What I expect to happen is obviously when the user fills the modal out the data is sent to the database which in return I will call and display on a table. What can I change or add to allow for the data to be inserted into my database?

Comment: Is this an AJAX problem, or a PHP problem? Did you check whether your database connector throws any error?

Comment: You checked if preparing the query might have failed - but for the actual _execution_ of the query, you are not checking at all.

Comment: There's no need for `$stmt->get_result()`. `INSERT` statements don't return any results.

Comment: @CBroe How could I check for that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong with my code and just wanted to add it here. My problem was that I had columns within my table that I was not inserting to. This is why my code was returning success but wasn't posting to my database.

Below is the code I updated to allow my code to work:

```
function createFile($createdby, $itemold, $itemnew, $startdatetime, $enddatetime, $approver1, $approver2, $approver3, $approver4, $approver5, $note){
  global $db;
  
  $dbs = new DatabaseApps($db);
  $conn = $dbs->getConnection();
  
  $note_esc = $conn->real_escape_string($note);
  
  $query = "INSERT INTO deviations (datetime, createdby, itemold, itemnew, startdatetime, enddatetime, approver1, approverdate1, approver2, approverdate2, approver3, approverdate3, approver4, approverdate4, approver5, approverdate5, note) VALUES (NOW(),?,?,?,?,?,?,0000-00-00,?,0000-00-00,?,0000-00-00,?,0000-00-00,?,0000-00-00,?)";
  
  
  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', $createdby, $itemold, $itemnew, $startdatetime, $enddatetime, $approver1, $approver2, $approver3, $approver4, $approver5, $note);
    $stmt->execute();
  } else {
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));
  }
  
  $dbs->closeConnection();
  
  return "success";
}
```